# Getting nullreferenceexception when calling RedisTypedClient.As<T> method

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

The question says it all..

We have been running it for 10 hrs when we suddenly hit this. I had to recycle IIS to recover from this..

Here is the stack trace..
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at ServiceStack.Redis.RedisClient.AsT
   at XXX.Cache.Providers.Redis.RedisCachedCollection`2.GetCollection(IRedisClient redis)
   at XXX.Cache.Providers.Redis.RedisCachedCollection`2.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

Here is the GetCollection method..

```
private IRedisHash<TKey, TValue> GetCollection(IRedisClient redis)
        {
            _redisTypedClient = redis.As<TValue>();
            return _redisTypedClient.GetHash<TKey>(_collectionKey);
        }
```

Comment: Is there a second exception saying the connection is lost?

Comment: Looks like the `redis` instance passed to the method be `null`? I'd add a guard to verify it's not null to ensure that's not the issue.

Comment: I have added retry from now, found that most the issues I have been seeing so far are due to some unknown intermittent failures on redis or from network. I have added retries to all of my calls and seem to be behaving much better.

Comment: As a follow up, how we recover from a redis lock if the IIS got reset or crashed. As a side affect of troubleshooting this, i found one my collections have been locked and all locking calls were timing out. I had to using redis-cli to flush db and let the cache rebuild.